# Constant Suggestions for AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am using autocompletetextview in my app and putting 4 items in my strings.xml file. When I type a letter, the dropdowm list is populated according to the letter I type. What I need it to do, however, is whenever I type a letter all the values from strings.xml must be shown in the dropdown list on autocompletetextview. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to subclass [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) so it does not send the text inside the EditText to the filter:

```
public class MyAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    public MyAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    // Allows you to show options on empty string.
    public boolean enoughToFilter() {
        return true;
    }
    // Override to always send an empty string.
    @Override
    protected void performFiltering(CharSequence text, int keyCode) {
        super.performFiltering("", 0);
    }
}
```